# グループ列があるデータセットの相関行列の作成

Tags: r

以下のような縦積みのデータセットでgroup別に相関行列をggpairs関数で作成したいのですが、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

```
ID value group
1   2     A
1   4     A
1   1     B
1   7     B
2   3     A
2   9     A
2   7     B
2   2     B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

既に解決済みと思われますが念のための御参考です。
グループ分けされたデータに `ggpairs()` を適用する例として，`group` で色分けし `ID` と `value` をグラフ化する記述例を下記に示します。

```
library(tidyverse)
library(GGally)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                 value = c(2, 4, 1, 7, 3, 9, 7, 2),
                 group = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B"))
df |>
    ggpairs(mapping = aes(color = group, alpha = 0.5),
            columns = c("ID", "value"))
```

[image: 出力画像]